Как называется анимация телеграмма
Я хорошо знаком с анимациями в Android, но потратив день так и не смог выяснить анимацию появления сторисов в телеграмме.
При потягивании вниз сначала увеличивается recycler view, где содержаться иконки пользователей.
Потом после появления, скорее после того как размеры иконок пользователей достигли до определенного размера останавливается масштабирование, с рывком.
И если еще потянуть то открывается контент на весь экран.
И наоборот, при скролле вверх - все уменьшается.
Не могу понять, как гуглить это, и как найти такое решение?
Где можно почитать?

Подобные анимации делаются через MotionLayout как программно, так и через xml файл. Возможности очень большие.
Видео на русском.
Дополнительная информация.
